# How can I use Azure data factory to migrate stored procedures between 2 SQL servers?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I need to write ADF pipelines to completely migrate all tables and stored procedures from one Azure SQL db to another.  I got a pipeline with foreach and copy activities to copy all tables, and want to do the same to migrate all stored procedures to new database.  How can I copy the stored procedures?

Any assistance is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ADF is not the right tool for this task.  Use the [Visual Studio Schema Compare](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-compare-two-sql-databases-from-visual-studio/) and Data Compare features instead.